# How to get data into crosswalk from Android

Tags: javascript, android, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I know we can get data from the Crosswalk HTML into android and toast it. But I have data from Android that I'd like to pass to the Javascript running in Crosswalk View. Any way to work around this ?

like using the gyroscope feed straight into the HTML or even bluetooth data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,
@JavaScriptInterface was used to call a function in native. 
So write a  native function to return a String back to  the javascript code on your html. For some weird reason returning int isnt working but strings work fine.